# How to configure an SFTP client Filezila to a machine which is accessible by doing SSH second time?

Tags: ssh, putty, sftp

MyMachine <---SSH---->  AccessMahcine <---SSH---->  Target Machine.

The target machine is accessible via SSH through an access machine.
I can SSH to access machine, and from there again SSH to the target machine.
Am able to connect successfully via Putty. But i was unable to configure an FTP client like Filezila. I tried tunnelling SSH port to local , and try to connect to it via Filezila. But it's connecting to the access machine only even though the Putty is currently connected on the Target machine.

Following are the steps i follow.

1. Connect Putty to Access machine
2. SSH to target machine from Putty window itself
3. Open Filezilla and connect
4. Filezilla connects and list folders. But folders are from access macine only. Not the currently connected target machine.

The putty and FileZilla configurations are as below.

- Putty tunnel port 22 to localhost:3111
- Filezilla connects to 127.0.0.1 port 3111

Filezilla connects and list folders. But folders are from access macine only. Not the currently connected target machine.

Comment: It all depends on the access machine's configuration.  Based on the information provided, I'm tempted to guess that it's probably intentionally not possible.

Comment: Look at  or contact the admin of the `access machine` and aas @Ajith suggested confine or deny  that  ProxyCommand or  some other  forwarding protocol IS working and running, if not as @ajith said its not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build the tunnel with putty that connects from your machine to the access one. It is important to specify the target machine address, not the port only.

Putty configuration (Connection / Tunnels):

Source port: `3111` (example, arbitrary number);
Destination: `[target_IP_or_name_as_seen_from_access_machine]:22`.
*Local*, *Auto*.

Then connect FileZilla to `sftp://127.0.0.1:3111`.

This assumes the target ssh is available on default port: `22`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update you saved my day. Changing tunnnel config destination to target machine IP made it worked